# jquery multiply contatins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to represent that in jquery:

```
    var menuItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var k = 0; k < menuItems.length; k++)
{
    if (menuItems[k].className == "menu")
    {
        var child = menuItems[k].firstChild;
        if (child.className == "menulink")
        {
            var tempSum = 0;
            tempSum += child.href.indexOf("bwshop");
            tempSum += child.href.indexOf("report");
            tempSum += child.href.indexOf("tutorial");
            tempSum += child.href.indexOf("chat");

            if (tempSum > 0) child.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

This is my fail not working code:

```
$("li.menu > a.menulink").filter(':contains("bwshop"), :contains("report"), :contains("tutorial"), :contains("chat")').hide();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) reads the inner text of the tag whereas your original code is searching in the `href` attribute.

You could change your code to use different selectors:

```
$("li.menu > a.menulink").filter('[href*="report"], [href*="tutorial"], [href*="chat"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.menu > a.menulink").filter(function() {
    return /(bwshop|report|tutorial|chat)/.test(this.href);
}).hide();
```